# comparing entities of list of lists and get the indexess for lists with more than two similar identities

Tags: python, list, compare

I have list of list as follows

Input:

```
[(21, 5, 4, 3), (21, 4, 1, 2), (21, 5, 1), (22, 8, 4, 2), (22, 4, 6, 7), (22, 8, 6)]
```

Each list in the list has always only integers. I would like to find the lists in which at least two entries are the same and then save and print the indexes of those list.

Output:

```
0 0 1
1 0 2
2 1 2
3 1 3
4 3 4
5 3 5
6 4 5
```

First column of the output in the index of the number of the pairs found.
2nd the 3rd column show the index of the lists which have 2 or more than 2 similar entities. 
If I can get a list of list where I have access to each element like list[0][0] would give 0 (first pair) and list[0][1] would give the first entity of the 1st pair and list[0][2] would give the 2nd entity of the 1st pair and so on. It would be even better so that I can parse it according to my requirement.

Parsing and printing would be no problem.

regards

Comment: Kindly provide the output explaination

Comment: Shouldn't the last line in the result be `6 4 5` instead since there's only 6 tuples?

Comment: @niemmi, you are right. My error. Exactly due to this reason I want to automate this :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the tuples to sets and do following:

```
d = [(21, 5, 4, 3), (21, 4, 1, 2), (21, 5, 1), (22, 8, 4, 2), (22, 4, 6, 7), (22, 8, 6)]
d = [set(l) for l in d]
index = 0
res = []

for i in xrange(len(d) - 1):
    for j in xrange(i + 1, len(d)):
        if len(d[i] & d[j]) >= 2:
            res.append([index, i, j])
            index += 1

print res # [[0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 2], [2, 1, 2], [3, 1, 3], [4, 3, 4], [5, 3, 5], [6, 4, 5]]
```

This works for Python 2.x, for 3.x you should use `range` instead of `xrange` and `print` function instead of statement.